# Why DataGrid does not show properties in Akgul.Maui.DataGrid library?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, maui

The problem with this code is that I do not receive any properties in the grid in app though in debbuging *Words* property `public ObservableCollection<Word> Words { get; }` is correctly populated with all data

## GridView

```
public GridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new BaseViewModel();
    }
```

## GetJson

```
    public Dictionary<string, string>? Json
    {
        get
        {
            var filePath = JsonFile.FilePath;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
        }
    }

    //public List<Word>? Words { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Word> LoadWords(Dictionary<string, string> _json)
    {
        var result = new ObservableCollection<Word>();
        foreach (var row in _json)
            if (JsonFile.FileName == "English.json" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Key))
                result.Add(new Word(row.Key)
                {
                    English = row.Value,
                    Polish = " ",
                    ToTranslate = " "
                });
            else if (JsonFile.FileName == "Polish.json" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Key))
                result.Add(new Word(row.Key)
                {
                    Polish = row.Value,
                    English = " ",
                    ToTranslate = " "
                });
            else if (JsonFile.FileName == "Translation.json" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Key))
                result.Add(new Word(row.Key)
                {
                    ToTranslate = row.Value,
                    English = " ",
                    Polish = " "
                });
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Key))
                result.Add(new Word(row.Key)
                {
                    ToTranslate = row.Value,
                    English = " ",
                    Polish = " "
                });
            else
                throw new Exception("Id cannot be null!");

        return result;
    }
```

## BaseViewModel

```
     private bool _isRefreshing;
    
    // Sharing ObservableCollection<Word>
    public ObservableCollection<Word> Words { get; set; }
    public Command RefreshCommand { get; set; }
    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get => _isRefreshing;
        set
        {
            _isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
        }
    }

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        var _getJson = new GetJson();
        Words=_getJson.LoadWords(_getJson.Json!);

        RefreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;

            // LoadWords();

            // wait 3 secs for demo
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            IsRefreshing = false;
        });
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
```

## DataGrid:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,70">
        <dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" SelectionEnabled="True"
                     RowHeight="50" HeaderHeight="30" BorderThickness="2"
                     PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
            <dg:DataGrid.NoDataView>
                <Label Text="Nothing to see here!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </dg:DataGrid.NoDataView>
            <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Id" PropertyName="Id" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="English" PropertyName="English" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Polish" PropertyName="Polish" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Translation" PropertyName="ToTranslate" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
            </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                <dg:PaletteCollection>
                    <Color>#F4F4F4</Color>
                    <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
                </dg:PaletteCollection>
            </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
        </dg:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

[Basically I get something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsfJs.png)
Without any properties. And there in the headers are just hard-coded name of Word model's properties.

Even funniest I get visible values when instead of *words* being got through: `var words = new GetWords().Words!;`

I get this value just by `var words = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Word[]>(" some url to .json string")`

There is  `Words=_getJson.LoadWords(_getJson.Json!);` that is an *ObservableCollection* right away and I do not know if it changes anything. Tried make it an array for the beggining and in a loop add it to the ObservableCollection and even making hard-coded new object did not made a trick.

Comment: if it does not work when you use `GetWords().Words` then the problem is probably in that class, which you did not post

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  For me it seems like ItemsSource doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yeah I solved this but I don't use it anymore since .NET MAUI doesn't support DataGrid officially (for all I know) and this one just look ugly and doesn't have dozens of functionalities built in.